# Django web app mail using Sendgrid or Amazon SES - Not receiving emails

Tags: python, django, email, sendgrid, amazon-ses

Thank you very much for helping people with software issues.
I'm developing a simple web application using Django, and I wanted to have a contact form so users can contact me for feedback and other topics. That mail would arrive in my Gmail for simpler communication.

I have followed many tutorials and update settings.py, forms.py, and views.py many times and I still have not received any email unless I send it via cmd like this:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    'validated email',
    ['validated email']
)
```

I have of course created accounts in both SendGrid and Amazon SES, validate the emails, and used the keys.

for views.py I have used these two contact views, one or the other, and I have modified any part of them many times trying to get the receive the email,  also validated email is the email I used with SES or Sendgrid.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import ContactForm
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.conf import settings

def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = ContactForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
            subject = "Contact" 
           body = {
           'first_name': form.cleaned_data['first_name'], 
            'last_name': form.cleaned_data['last_name'], 
            'email': form.cleaned_data['email'], 
            'message':form.cleaned_data['message'], 
            }
            message = "\n".join(body.values())

            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, 'validated email', ['validated email'], fail_silently=False) 
            except BadHeaderError: #add this
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')   
            

    form = ContactForm()
    return render(request, 'contact.html', {'form':form})
```

**or**

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':    
    
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
                
            try:               
                first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
                last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
                email = request.POST.get('email')
                message = request.POST.get('message')              
    
                send_mail(first_name, last_name, email, message, 'validated email', ['validated email'], fail_silently=False)

            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
                
        return HttpResponse('Thank you')
        
    form = ContactForm
    return render(request, 'contact.html', {'form':form})
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms


class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length = 50)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length = 50)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length = 150)
    message = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea, max_length = 2000)
```

I have actually manipulated plenty of times the settings for both companies, quitting and adding code but any change seems to work.

**Amazon SES settings.py**

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_ses.SESBackend'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '***CM7Y7'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '***n8GKA+sp80cY'
AWS_SES_REGION_NAME = 'eu-west-2' #(ex: us-east-2)
AWS_SES_REGION_ENDPOINT ='email.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com' #(ex: email.us-east-2.amazonaws.com)
```

**Sendgrid settings.py**

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey' # this is exactly the value 'apikey'
SENDGRID_API_KEY = 'SG.JFR****' # this is your API key
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'sgbackend.SendGridBackend'
SENDGRID_SANDBOX_MODE_IN_DEBUG = True
SENDGRID_ECHO_TO_STDOUT = True
```

**form part of contact.html**

```
<form class="border-right pr-5 mb-5" method="post" id="contactForm" name="contactForm">
               {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="First name">             
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="Last name">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="7" placeholder="Write your message"></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-primary rounded-0 py-2 px-4">
                    <span class="submitting"></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                
              </form>
```

In the command prompt and using the developer's tools of chrome and firefox, everything seems to work, but I'm not receiving any email in my Gmail account not also in the spam folder. I would really appreciate it if you can please help me because I have checked plenty of tutorials and posts, editing many code but still not seeing it working. Thank you very much in advance any suggestion will be welcome.

Comment: you could use HTML formsubmit, much simpler for sending emails to a specific address. Not the most secure, but works

Comment: @beatmaister Thanks! I'm going to google it and check if it can be a good alternative!